# How to append a Modal to root element?

Tags: react-native, root-element

I need to append a `Modal` to `root element` of a `React-Native` application which I didn't write. But I know there is a `root element` there.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean precisely? You want to show a modal on a react-native app? Something like [this](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/how-to-create-a-modal-in-react-3coc)?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes, I want to show a modal on a react-native app, but I can't import it to the main page of product. so I've decided to append it to the root element. is there any way to do that? I mean showing modal without using a component, but by appending it to main screen.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think you could do that... Let's wait, maybe there is someone that konws =)

Comment: sure =) lets wait for others :)

Comment: is this not gonna do it? https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

Comment: Since you know where your root element is, just need to add the sample code from the doc, into your root element

Comment: @Isaac I know there is a root, but I don't have its code. I'm writing a NPM package which needs to show a Modal. but I don't want users to insert my Modal component in their code, but instead I want them to call a function, and I do the rest for them.

Comment: It's quite simple then, you just need install react-native-modal, and check the source code from `node_modules`

Comment: @Isaac I'm a newbie, can you please give me a ref to see an example ?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal take this as an example
and this is the source code https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/blob/master/src/modal.tsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236449/discussion-between-danoosh-jooybar-and-isaac).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple then, you just need install react-native-modal, and check the source code from node_modules

http://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal
take this as an example and this is the source code
https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/blob/master/src/modal.tsx

this answer was made by https://stackoverflow.com/users/9816472/isaac in comments